# Why SetState not executed on componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I want to update a state in ComponentDidMount but the setState function is not being executed

```
ComponentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.location.search.includes("?token")) {
      const email = getQueryVariable(this.props.location.search, "email");
      const token = getQueryVariable(this.props.location.search, "token");
      if (this.state.showValidationModal === false) {
        console.log("Before",this.state.showValidationModal);
        this.setState({
          showValidationModal:true
        })
        console.log("After",this.state.showValidationModal);

      }
    }
  }
```

when the application gets mounted the result of both showValidationModal log are `false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState` is an async operation, it doesn't update the state immediately, But the `setState` callback, has the last instance value from the state, So.

```
ComponentDidMount() {
if (this.props.location.search.includes("?token")) {
  const email = getQueryVariable(this.props.location.search, "email");
  const token = getQueryVariable(this.props.location.search, "token");
  if (this.state.showValidationModal === false) {
    console.log("Before",this.state.showValidationModal);
    this.setState({
      showValidationModal:true
    })
    // here you get the latest value of showValidationModal state
    this.setState(prevState => console.log(prevState.showValidationModal))

    // here you get the old value.
    console.log("After",this.state.showValidationModal);

  }
}
}
```